# Calculations in the field $\mathbb{F}_{13}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

The text i am reading claims that $\frac{246}{14}=1$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. However, i cannot figure out why this is correct. Since $13 \cdot 18 = 234 \Rightarrow 246 = 12$ and $14 = 1$. How is $12 = 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$? I appreciate the help.

Comment: You got it right. It's $-1$. Another way of seeing that is to observe that $260=20\cdot13=0$, so $246=260-14=-14$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jyrki Lahtonen in the comments, your calculation is correct and the text is incorrect.